# Liquid Shopify - Display specific products on custom landing page

Tags: shopify, liquid

Is it possible to write a loop where I can display specific products that belong to different collections on a custom liquid landing page (e.g., filename `templates\page.[page-title].liquid`)?

Here is an example of my loop:

```
<div id="recommended-products">
    <!-- Begin loop with specific products (Perhaps by id?) -->
        <div class="product-card">
            <div class="product-card__title">{{ product.title | escape  }}</div>
            <div class="product-card__price">
                {% if product.price_varies %}
                    {{ product.price_min | money }} - {{ product.price_max | money }}
                {% else %}
                    {{ product.price | money }}
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
    <!-- End loop -->
</div>
```

Thank you for you time.

Comment: Hi! why don't you try the collection based method

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion. Unfortunately the client has these items in several collections. Some of the items on those collections I would like to exclude. :\

Edit: Perhaps I should try the tag method?

Comment: ok can i post my code without any css but the code is working properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shopify Select Any Product Block Code

```
{%- for block in section.blocks -%}
{%- assign product = block.settings.product -%}
<img src="{{ product.featured_image | img_url: 'master' }}">
<div class="Product_detail">
 {{ product.title | escape }}
{% render 'price', product: product, price_class: '' %}
</div>
{%- endfor -%}

{% schema %}
  {
    "name": "product",
    "settings": [],
  "blocks": [
    {
      "type": "Product",
      "name": "Product block",
      "settings": [
        {
      "type": "product",
      "id": "product",
      "label": "t:sections.featured-product.settings.product.label"
        }
    ]

    }
  ],
  "presets": [
    {
      "name": "products"
    }
  ]
  }
{% endschema %}
```